# Confidence intervals for predicted probabilities from predict.lrm

Tags: r, rms

I am trying to determine confidence intervals for predicted probabilities from a binomial logistic regression in R. The model is estimated using `lrm` (from the package `rms`) to allow for clustering standard errors on survey respondents (each respondent appears up to 3 times in the data):

```
library(rms)
model1<-lrm(outcome~var1+var2+var3,data=mydata,x=T,y=T,se.fit=T)
model.rob<-robcov(model1,cluster=respondent.id)
```

I am able to estimate a predicted probability for the outcome using `predict.lrm`:

```
predicted.prob<-predict(model.rob,newdata=data.frame(var1=1,var2=.33,var3=.5),
type="fitted")
```

What I want to determine is a 95% confidence interval for this predicted probability. I have tried specifying `se.fit=T`, but this not permissible in `predict.lrm` when `type=fitted`.

I have spent the last few hours scouring the Internet for how to do this with `lrm` to no avail (obviously). Can anyone point me toward a method for determining this confidence interval? Alternatively, if it is impossible or difficult with `lrm` models, is there another way to estimate a logit with clustered standard errors for which confidence intervals would be more easily obtainable?

Comment: Close as more appropriate on another SE site. Without a data example, this is only a statistical question. Furthermore, Frank is more likely to see it over at CrossValidated.com than he is here, anyway.

Comment: I'm unclear on which site is more appropriate for this type of question.  The question is about programming but definitely touches on stat.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I was considering offering the `exp(fit +/- 1.96*se)/(1+ exp(fit +/- 1.96*se) )` strategy but after looking at `?predict.lrm` figured there was a reason you didn't provide that. I thought perhaps there was a problem with not taking into account the covariances. As you can see, I hadn't gone down through the examples. And I falsely imagined you might not see it as soon if it sat here.

Answer (score 4):

The help file for `predict.lrm` has a clear example.  Here is a slight modification of it:

```
L <- predict(fit, newdata=data.frame(...), se.fit=TRUE)
plogis(with(L, linear.predictors + 1.96*cbind(- se.fit, se.fit)))
```

For some problems you may want to use the `gendata` or `Predict` functions, e.g.

```
L <- predict(fit, gendata(fit, var1=1), se.fit=TRUE)  # leave other vars at median/mode
Predict(fit, var1=1:2, var2=3)   # leave other vars at median/mode; gives CLs
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - works like a charm. I have one follow-up question: can a similar strategy be used for determining confidence intervals for predicted probabilities from an ordered logistic regression (i.e., the probability of landing in one of the top two categories of a scale as opposed to the bottom two)?

Comment: Yes.  See `kint` argument to `Predict`.